# Angulartics2 initial setup

Tags: angular, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, angulartics, angulartics2

can someone explain to me how to set-up angulartics2 in angular 5??? I have read so many different variations that I am not sure what is currently working anymore.

I would like to hook it to Google analytics.

Answer (score 0):

I just got it setup using angular 6 by following their github guide.

https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2

I would assume the process is no different for angular 5